# Kivy and discovering devices with bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, kivy

I have seen here (https://gist.github.com/tito/7432757) how to use pyjnius to access the java classes using kivy to connect via bluetooth.  What I am trying to do is to discover new devices and connect to them insecurely using sdp.  I'm not sure how to receive the results of `startDiscovery()` in kivy.  In java you have to use a broadcast receiver.  Do I have to use the pyjnius to access the broadcast receiver from android as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've missed the [BroadcastReceiver](http://python-for-android.readthedocs.org/en/latest/android/#module-android.broadcast) in the Python-for-android / `android.broadcast` module :) It does exactly what you need, it's an implementation in Java / Pyjnius that allows you to receive the result in Python.

Note that the actions you need to listen need to be written in lowercase, without the `ACTION_` prefix.

A mockup for your application can look like this:

```
class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        self.br = BroadcastReceiver(
            self.on_broadcast, actions=['found'])
        self.br.start()

    def on_broadcast(self, context, intent):
        # called when a device in found
        pass

    # Don't forget to stop and restart the receiver when the app is going
    # to pause / resume mode

    def on_pause(self):
        self.br.stop()
        return True

    def on_resume(self):
        self.br.start()
```

Comment: Link in answer doesnt exist anymore.

Comment: Example seems to be here now> https://github.com/Android-for-Python/BroadcastReceiver_examples/blob/main/Bluetooth_scanner_example/main.py