# Python kivy locally share a variable between phones

Tags: python, android, ios, bluetooth, kivy

I would like to make an ios app using kivy or some other python app framework and have the app run in the background. When two users are in proximity it will execute python code that broadcasts a message for other phones in the area to receive. How would I go about doing this? Thanks for any responses!

Comment: Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26317101/kivy-and-discovering-devices-with-bluetooth

Comment: Does this also work with IOS?